# Generate pages on the basis of links with jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm newbie with Jekyll and maybe I have to find alternative ways.
I would like to achieve the following goal:

- I want to avoid having my code replaced in everywhere (for the layout).  I have to generate a page on the basis of the previous link.

So, I have the following architecture.

x.html
Here I have the link to bigcomponent.html

```
<article>
    <div id="{{entry.id}}" class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left">
                {{ entry.title }}
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span class="label label-success">{{entry.projects}}</span>

            </div>

            <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right: 7px;">

<span class="label label-success status" >{{entry.status}}</span>
            </div>

            </p>
        </div><!-- panel-heading closed -->
        <div class="panel-body"> 
            <div class="container-fluidrm">
             {% if entry.picture %} <img src="{{entry.picture}}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" > {% else %} No-picture {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-body closed -->
        <div class="panel-footer" style="height:120px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">

                    <p>Description: {{entry.description}}</p>


                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <a href="bigcomponent.html"><span id= "logos" class="material-icons">&#xE85B;</span></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left:7px;" >
                    <span id= "logos" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-footer closed -->


    </div><!-- panel closed -->

</article>
```

bigcomponent.html
Here I would like to use a parameter to include the right content in my layout.

```
{% include bigcomponents/{{include.param}}/description.html %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full">
{% include head.html %}

    <body class="full">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="componentscontainer">

                <div class="col-md-9">                  
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" id ="panelcomponentlarge">
                        <div class="panel-heading " >{{page.title}}

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                                    {% include bigcomponents/{{include.param}}/code.html %}

                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <!-- highlight -->
                                <div class="col-md-9">

                                    HTML:

                                    {% highlight html linenos%}
                                        {% include bigcomponents/{{include.param}}/code.html %}
                                    {% endhighlight %}

                                </div>
                                <!-- end hightlight -->
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    Change Log
                                </div>
                            </div><!--row-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-10">
                                        <span id= "logos" style="font-size: 50px; vertical-align: middle;" class="material-icons">&#xE906;</span> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <span id= "logos" style="font-size: 44px; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 2px;" class="material-icons">&#xE838;</span>

                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--panel-->
                </div> <!--column-->
                <div class="col-md-3" id="relatedcomponents">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p> Second </p>
                        <div class="Row">
                            {% assign fullcomponents = site.components %}
                            {% for entry in fullcomponents %}
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                 {% include componentfirst.html %}
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure that there is a smart way to get it done.

Comment: Can you synthesize your requirements ? For now, it's not clear what you've tryed. So, it's not clear to explore solutions.

Comment: `{% include bigcomponents/{{include.param}}/description.html %}` It looks like you're trying to dynamically include different components. Jekyll isn't what you want for that kind of work - checkout [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) or [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/).